# How to customize the add media button, popup with my custom html in the popup window after clicking the button in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, editor, media-buttons

I have the below code. I need a button like add media in the edit page of admin, in which on click shows a popup and displays my custom html with a form in it.

I tried with below but I am getting the unnecessary things like Upload files tab, Media library tab etc., I don't need all these but I just need my custom form on button clicked.

index.php

```
function add_cp_media_button() {
  echo '<a href="#" id="cp-forms-btn" class="button">cp Forms</a>';
}

function include_cp_media_button_js_file() {
  wp_enqueue_script('media_button', plugins_url( '/js/cp.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_media', 'include_cp_media_button_js_file');
```

cp.js

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cp-forms-btn').click(open_media_window);
    });

    function open_media_window() {

    //I want to display the form with select drop down with my names populated in the dropdown, after selecting the item, I need to insert the text to the editor.

    }

});
```

Could someone help me on this

Comment: Is this what you need? https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-a-media-button-to-the-content-editor/

Comment: Yes. But that does not show how to add our html content within the popup window.

Comment: I have used thickbox() in wordpress and its working.